# netbeans jvi vimrc file location

Tags: netbeans, vim, jvi

I have started using netbeans vim plugin Jvi and i cant seem to find the vimrc file location
I found an option that seem to say that it will save the vimrc in the home folder, but there isnt one there.

I am using Ubuntu.
thanks

Answer (score 6):

jVi does not support vimscript, so it does not handle a vimrc file. As mentioned, you can configure jVi in NetBeans with

Tools > Options > jViConfig

Answer (score 1):

For most vi-like systems the .vimrc file is optional - if it is there, the program will use it, if it isn't it'll just use the defaults.

From a brief look at the [jVi sourceforge page](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/ReadmeNetBeans.html) it seems as if the settings in the GUI are equivalent to creating a .vimrc file - so you can either set the details there, or create your own .vimrc.