# jVi in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, vim, jvi

I'm choosing what to use: Eclipse or NetBeans. NetBeans has better vim plugin - jVi, but, as I see, it doesn't work with my own ~/.vimrc file. But in eclipse and VimPlugin for it everything is perfect. So are there any ways to use my vimrc settings for NetBeans with jVi?

Comment: did you find the answer? what are you using now?

Comment: @bahodir No, I didn't find the answer. NetBeans has ugly fonts so I just work with Eclipse without any such plugins.

Comment: I've tried both ... many times. And one more time I've settled with Netbeans. When you say 'ugly fonts', are you referring to code fonts or menu etc. fonts? As for jVi, in the options menu you can more or less configure it.

Comment: As mentioned in answer to [netbeans jvi vimrc file location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676675/netbeans-jvi-vimrc-file-location) jVi does not understand vimscript, so no vimrc handling. In NetBeans use Menu>Tools>Options>jViConfig.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to.  jvi uses the files in $HOME/.netbeans/${version}/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/ for configuration.  Namely it uses jvi.properties for any values that you've set that differ from the default.  Otherwise it uses the defaults that are tucked away inside of some .jar in $HOME/.netbeans/${version}/modules .

Comment: Is it possible to add vim plugins or syntax files that jVi can use?

Comment: Negative.  jVi is really just the vi keybindings (and a subset of commands for command mode) applied to the Netbeans Editor, as opposed to an actual vi instance.  All of the syntax highlighting is still done internal to Netbeans.  jVI will not be able to handle vi plugins either since it really isn't a true vi instance.